# Display html and pass the data from html to mongoose server

Tags: c, mongoose-web-server

I want to dispaly html page through mongoose web server but when i try to load the page using mg_send_file(conn,filename) css and js files does not get loaded is there any other way to load the html through mongoose server and pass the data entered in the html back to the webserver.